# How to use dynamic filter in sql procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql, procedure

I want use Dynamic filter in sql Procedure 
,like this

Select * from Table Where @Filter

Can I Write Like That Or Was Diffrent Ways to Use
I must Use this Syntax because I Want Remove Select in Application and Use Procedure.

Comment: You need dynamic query

Comment: Yes , How Can Write A Procedure With this Condition???

Comment: did you ever try add paramater  in your procedure?

Comment: That is a very basic question. There are many tutorials out there

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DynamicFilter
(
    -- Optional Filters for Dynamic Search
    @COLUMN1       INT = NULL,
    @COLUMN2       NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @COLUMN3       NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @COLUMN4       NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM TableName
    WHERE
        (@COLUMN1 IS NULL OR Column1 = @COLUMN1)
    AND (@COLUMN2 IS NULL OR Column2 LIKE '%' + @COLUMN2 + '%')
    AND (@COLUMN3 IS NULL OR Column3 LIKE '%' + @COLUMN3 + '%')
    AND (@COLUMN4 IS NULL OR Column4 LIKE '%' + @COLUMN4 + '%')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spProcedurName
 @Filter  datatype
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   FROM Table
   WHERE columnName= @Filter

END
```

You can paramater like that.

Comment: I fine a better Way that like this

Answer (score 0):

@Query='
 Select * from table' + @Filter

exec @Query